how to redefine \textdagger to palatino font?
I want to write all \textdagger and \textdaggerdbl with the palatino font.
For example, I like:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textdagger\textdaggerdbl

{\usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}
\textdagger\textdaggerdbl}
\end{document}

However, the following approach does not work:
\let\oldtextdagger\textdagger
\def\textdagger{\usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}\oldtextdagger}

\textdagger

What's wrong with this?

Use \NewCommandCopy instead of \let.
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy{\oldtextdagger}{\textdagger}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\textdagger}{}{%
  {\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont\oldtextdagger}%
}
\NewCommandCopy{\oldtextdaggerdbl}{\textdaggerdbl}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\textdaggerdbl}{}{%
  {\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont\oldtextdaggerdbl}%
}

\begin{document}

X\textdagger\textdaggerdbl Y

\end{document}


You can replace \fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont with \usefont{TS1}{ppl}{m}{n}, if you so prefer. The symbol will not change according to the context, though.
